# Number of combinations of ages of 3 children

Tags: combinatorics

Your neighbor has $3$ children and you always forget how old they are. However, you know their ages are all different, and the oldest is at most $15$ years old while the youngest is at least $7$. How many possibilities are there for their ages?

> Is there an effective way of solving this without brute forcing? I was thinking of a stars and bars approach but I do not think that would account for the ages being distinct. My best approach thus far is to count all ages the children could be conditioned on the age of the oldest child and iterate from $15$ down to $9$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=\{7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15\}$

$n(S)=9$

$\implies$ the number of possibilities are $$\binom{9}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends if the ages of the children are distinct or not. If the ages of the children are distinct, then there are $9$ possible ages and $3$ children each of different ages, so there should be $\binom{9}{3}$ for the ages. However, if the ages are not distinct, then you are correct that you should do a stars and bars approach in that this is the same as asking how many ways are there to put $3$ balls into $9$ buckets (each ball represents a kid and the bucket you place it into represents the age of the kid), and in that case there will be $\binom{11}{3}$ different possibilities for the ages of the kids. However, there is also the case in which you know that the kids are distinct say it is Alice, Bob, and Charlie, and in that case there are $9$ possibilities for each kids age giving $9^3$ different ways for the kids ages.

Comment: The ages are all different